# How to access a theme color in bootstrap 5?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-themes

I want to define my own theme color so the standard bootstrap elemets are overriden and also use the value later for my own components. Here is the code I use in a scss file:

```
$theme-colors: (
    "primary": #611fe6,
    "secondary": #ffbd58,
    "dark": #000000
);

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";


.fa-li {
    color: $primary;
}
```

.fa-li then has the original primary color of bootstrap and not my own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "How to access a theme color in bootstrap 5?"

**Short answer**, use `map-get`...

```
.fa-li {
    color: map-get($theme-colors,"primary")
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/dmHvBcQ5DT)

---

> "I want to define my own theme color so the standard bootstrap elements
> are overridden and also use the value later for my own components"

**Full answer**, For your theme changes it would be better to redefine the value of `$primary`. Then you won't have to use `map-get`. Simply reference `$primary`...

```
$primary: #611fe6;
$secondary: #ffbd58;
$dark: #000000;

@import "bootstrap";

.fa-li {
    color: $primary
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/6Z9pPJ5zFP)

---

Also see: [Overriding Bootstrap SCSS Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029128/overriding-bootstrap-scss-variables)