# How to obtain color codes from bs_theme() in Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny, bootswatch

I'm running R Shiny and I'm setting a theme:

```
theme = bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = "pulse")
```

How do I obtain the color codes for the primary color, the secondary color, and so on? I have seen an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504785/how-to-access-a-theme-color-in-bootstrap-5) where the provided CSS code is:

```
.fa-li {
    color: map-get($theme-colors,"primary")
}
```

How do I translate this to R code?

Comment: You can run your a dummy app with the `bs_theme` specified and inspect it in your browser. Then search in the inspector for `--bs-primary` etc.

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to automatically refer to the colors for any theme, i.e. I want to be able to quickly change theme and use the theme colors in ggplot2 objects etc.

Comment: I doubt you can get those with R. `theme <- bslib::bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = "pulse"); str(theme)`  references saas files.

Comment: But since R itself can reach these codes, I feel like I should be able to somehow? I know nothing about saas but shouldn't I be able to point R to manually read some file and save the relevant strings from it?

Comment: It doesn't have to literally be R code, but I want to be able to get the results into my script, maybe I can put the above CSS inline in R somehow to get what I want?

Comment: That should be possible with parsing text files in the theme. You might also want to look at https://rstudio.github.io/thematic/

Comment: Good recommendation, hadn't heard of! :)